# Display video file from mongodb with grids-stream.js and express.js 4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, video

I begin to use driver of mongodb grid-stream.js with node.js to my DB store. Everything was good except when I try display my video stored in mongodb. It shows as if it were a file download. This is the code that I have:

```
function SendFile(res,id){

    var readStream=gfs.createReadStream({
        _id:id
    }).on('open',function(){
        console.log("start..");

    }).on('data',function(chunk){

        console.log('loading..');
        //loading...

    }).on("end",function(){

        console.log("ready");
        //loaded :)

    }).on('error', function (err){

        res.send(404);//no found :(
        console.log(err);

    });

    readStream.pipe(res);

};

app.get("/:video",function(req,res){

    SendFile(res,req.params.video); 

});//get file video
```

I think the line `readStream.pipe(res);` is the problem I think that behaves like `res.download` but a need to behave like:

[Video example](https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/F184C6C3601088988371424276480_2b53f186e8e.0.4.8649904460317250188.mp4?versionId=CmvIIrhvYF02A9yc46FdBiii2dC0jqBb)

Comment: I found the solution had to define certain things for the response to be validated thanks anyway

res.header("Content-Type","video/mp4");
res.header("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
res.header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
res.header("Content-Length",903746);
readStream.pipe(res); this way response the video how example and not like auto download file [examples](https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/F184C6C3601088988371424276480_2b53f186e8e.0.4.8649904460317250188.mp4?versionId=CmvIIrhvYF02A9yc46FdBiii2dC0jqBb)

Comment: I just marked your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24900944/2313887) about this as a duplicate since this contains more information. Please use the "edit" link on your own question to add additional information in the future, rather than post new questions or comments on your own question.